# React updating a setState with a callback to a useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I am updating the `setStates` I am using from class based components to functional ones. I have a few usecases where theres a closure. the code is

```
this.setState(

  ({ notifications }) => ({

    notifications: [...notifications, notification],

  }),

  () =>

    timeout !== undefined && window.setTimeout(closeNotification, timeout)

);
```

How do I use the `useState` hook to update this. I assume useState doesnt return a promise, so I cant use a `.then`. If thats the case, whats the best way to update this function?

Comment: You can use `useEffect` hook to run some code _after_ state has been updated. For this to work, you will need to add the state in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: thats kind of what i figured Id have to do. I was just hoping there was a more linear way to go about the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like so?

```
const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

const doSomething = () => {
  setNotifications([ /* ... */ ]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  let timer;
  if(timeout !== undefined) {
    timer = setTimeout(closeNotification, timeout);
  }

  return () => clearTimeout(timer)
}, [notifications]);
```

Comment: `useEffect` should return a unmounting cleanup function, which could clear the timeout to avoid leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useState` and the `useEffect` hooks to achieve the same result like so:

```
const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    // Close Notifications Here

}, [notifications]);

// To update the state use the setNotifications function like so
setNotifications(prevState => [...prevState, newNotification]);
```

the `useEffect` hook will run whenever you update the notifications.